# Removing or highlighting duplicate values from same row (client order) (but not from a different order)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2021

I have let's say, some client orders (each order is different or belongs to different client) and I want in the same order to check if there is a duplicate model input on the model category as shown below.
For example in order 1 there are two models with same name (sm150, 1st and last) and i want to find a way to highlight it or to show a warning message or even better to identify it and automatically remove it OR add the remaining stock and price to the first row's stock and price for the same model.

Thank you in advance for your help.

[image: excel img example]

I tried with filter function to separate each order and then countif but becomes really hard computation wise, for excel to check each different product.

Sample data:

| Ord -1 |  |  | Mic Shura | sm150 | test22 | 9 | 9 | 25/3/2024 | 26/3/2024 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | Piano Thomman | cronos | test23 | 7 | 8 | 25/3/2024 | 26/3/2024 |
|  |  |  | Mic Shura | sm150b | test24 | 6 | 6 | 25/3/2024 | 26/3/2024 |
|  |  |  | Mic Shura | sm150 | test23 | 8 | 7 | 25/3/2024 | 26/3/2024 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Ord-2 |  |  | Mic Shura | sm150c | none | 12 | 10 | 25/3/2024 | 26/3/2024 |
|  |  |  | Guitar Bayer | bayleaf | none | 9 | 98 | 25/3/2024 | 26/3/2024 |
|  |  |  | Guitar Siem | yama5000 | no | 1 | 8 | 25/3/2024 | 26/3/2024 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Can you put your sample data in a table using this [markdown](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)?

Comment: Please post sample data using [Markdown_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/) and show your expected output

Answer (score 1):

I will just assume you have put your data like below in `A1:D5`:

| model | accessories | stock | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sm150 | test22 | 9 | 9 |
| cronos | test23 | 7 | 8 |
| sm150b | test24 | 6 | 6 |
| sm150 | test23 | 8 | 7 |

To group data by Model, and sum up Stock and Cost, you can use below formula:

```
=LET(models, A2:A5, unique_models, UNIQUE(models,FALSE,FALSE),stocks,C2:C5, costs, D2:D5, HSTACK(unique_models, MAP(unique_models,LAMBDA(x,SUMPRODUCT(stocks,--(models=x)))), MAP(unique_models,LAMBDA(x,SUMPRODUCT(costs,--(models=x))))))
```

Basically, the  formula is made up of two maps:

The first one sums up Stocks by model:

```
MAP(unique_models,LAMBDA(x,SUMPRODUCT(stocks,--(models=x))))
```

The second one sums up Costs by model:

```
MAP(unique_models,LAMBDA(x,SUMPRODUCT(stocks,--(models=x))))
```

The results is like below:

[image]

Alternatively, if you have `GROUPBY`, you can just use this:

```
=GROUPBY(A1:A5,C1:D5,SUM,3,0)
```

[image]

Apologies I didn't realise you cannot use MAP.
You mentioned your table is in `E2:H2000`, so you can add another input below formula in column I:

```
=COUNTIF($E$2:$E$2000;E2)>1
```

As for conditional formatting, here is how the rule should be set up:

[image]

Then in column J, you can add below formula to sum stock.

```
=IF(I2;SUMIF($E$2:$E$2000;E2;$G$2:$G$2000);G2)
```

In column K, use below to sum costs:

```
=IF($I2;SUMIF($E$2:$E$2000;$E2;$H$2:$H$2000);$H2)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I am getting a #Name error though.

Since your solution is too complicated for me, if you had time I would love to learn what its function does and process of your thinking!

I modified only the tables as follows but its producing an error:

=LET(models; E2:E2000; unique_models; UNIQUE(models;FALSE;FALSE);stocks;G2:G2000; costs; H2:H2000; HSTACK(unique_models; MAP(unique_models;LAMBDA(x;SUMPRODUCT(stocks;--(models=x)))); MAP(unique_models;LAMBDA(x;SUMPRODUCT(costs;--(models=x))))))

The error seems to be on the models variable you create

Comment: Also since I can not change the table, would it be possible for excel to just identify the duplicate and highlight it or just add up the cost and stock in one row.
Maybe with VBA but that becomes more complicated for no reason.

Lastly, i think I can not use the map function since it does not exist on my excel pro plus2021

Comment: Sorry, I saw you mentioned FILTER so I just assume MAP is also available in your excel

Comment: If you want to check duplicates, you can use `=COUNTIF($E$2:$E$2000;E2)>1`, and then use conditional formating.

Comment: yea i had that idea but it does not differentiate between different orders sadly...

Comment: maybe adding a condition like =COUNTIF($E$2:$E$2000;E2;$A$2:$A$2000;"<>"A2)>1?
But my knowledge in excel is very very limited so this is a hypothesis

Comment: I think it is better to use `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$2000;A2;$E$2:$E$2000;E2)>1`.

Comment: But I noticed your Order Number is in a merged cell. is it possible for you to un-merge it? if not, COUNTIFS won't work.

Comment: yeap not possible since in 1 order we can have many products models.

Comment: Can't you just add a new column to write Order Num in un-merged cells? e.g Row1-Row5 are for Order1, then you can write 1 in `I1:I5`, and use `=COUNTIFS($I$2:$I$2000;I2;$E$2:$E$2000;E2)>1` to check duplicates. you can even make the column width = 0.0001 for `column I` to make it invisible.

Comment: yes i did that in the end because it seems pretty hard otherwise. Could you elaborate a little bit more on this solution so i could understand it better? Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: 1. Use `COUNNTIFS` to find duplicates. 2. use conditional formatting based on the result of `COUNNTIFS` to highlight the row. 3. use `SUMIF` to sum up models that are duplicated.

Comment: yeap did it tnx u for the time and effort. 
I decided not to use sumif coz i grouped the price per order in another column.